# Check if a row exists or not in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have seen many posts about this in SO. But I could not get an answer.
I want to the query to check if a particular row exists or not in a table. If it exists, it should return me a **string** true and stop the search there itself and if not return false.

Comment: What have you tried? How do you specify the row? By rowid or the values of all attributes? Does it have to be a query or is a PL/SQL function acceptable as well?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
select
  case when exists (select true from table_name where table_column=?)
    then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end;
```

But it would be better to just return boolean instead of string:

```
select exists (select true from table_name where table_column=?);
```

Answer (score -17):

Spoiler:

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH magic AS (
        WITH lousy AS ( SELECT * FROM one  WHERE num = -1)
        SELECT 'True'::text AS truth
        WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM lousy)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'False'::text AS truth
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM lousy)
        )
SELECT *
FROM magic
        ;
```

Comment: It was intended as a spoiler. The OP is definitely homework, and shows no effort.

Comment: What you wrote is gibberish even for me. You don't tutor providing an deliberately obfuscated example that is working but [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) worthy. You could for example point to documentation of `case` and `exists`, as it is useful only for somebody that knows what to look for.

Comment: It does work, and produces the correct result. Let the OP explain it to his teacher. And he could look up the syntax for case and exists himself, too. Or for the CTE.

Comment: @Ashwin: because SQL does not _need_ an `if ..` condition. Ussage of `if ...` implies procedural/sequential processing. In SQL, there is `WHERE ...` which is applied to the whole set. (and an empty set is also a set)

Comment: -1 Other people besides the OP read this answer trying to solve their own similar problems.

Comment: @LeviStanley : and they can try the other solution (which has more credits, obviously) or mine (which is different and strange, but actually **works**) If they don't like my style they should develop their own style. (which the already have otherwise they would not dislike mine)

Comment: Please note that the OP dis not show any effort, whatsoever. This is just a _gimmethecodez_ question, which can be anwered by anybode sufficiently fluent in SQL (there might even be more methods to get to the same goal than just these two answers)

Comment: This is a really confusing way to check for existence and I'd be really surprised if it wasn't brutally slow in a real-world scenario.

Comment: @redbmk: It will certainly not be slow. (at most twice as slow as Tometzky 's award-winning answer) Why do you think it is slow?

Comment: @wildplasser well I haven't tested it so I guess you could call it a hunch, but basically you're creating a temp table, querying it twice, then unioning that. Postgres iirc has some optimizations to handle `exists` pretty efficiently, but I'd imagine it would get a pretty wacky plan doing it that way.

Comment: No, a CTE is not a temp table. Even if it were, it would be a one-tuple table, completely cached in buffers. No need to write it back to disk, either.