# PostgreSQL - check if a row is completely filled in

Tags: postgresql

I've seen questions for [checking if a row merely exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274451/check-if-a-row-exists-or-not-in-postgresql), But I haven't seen anything (on SO or elsewhere) about whether or not *all* the data is filled in.

I was hoping that `SELECT true FROM myTable WHERE name='myRow' AND * IS NOT NULL;` would work, but it doesn't.

What wildcard will work in place of the asterisk, if there is one? Will I have to put in each column name into the query individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed reference the whole row, but not using `*`, but by using the table name:

```
SELECT true 
FROM myTable 
WHERE name='myRow' 
  AND myTable IS NOT NULL;
```

The `IS NOT NULL` operator on a row value returns true if **all** columns of the row are not null.

The following statement:

```
with mytable (col1, col2, col3) as (
values 
  (1,null,null),
  (null,1,null), 
  (null,null,1),
  (1,1,1)
) 
select *
from mytable 
where mytable is not null;
```

will return:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----+------+-----
   1 |    1 |    1
```

---

The opposite btw. is not true. `where mytable is null` will not return anything because a row is by definition never null (because then it wouldn't exist). To find rows where at least one column is null you would need to use `where not (mytable  is not null)`

A similar problem is described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/143959/1822